# virtualenv compile fails to find python27.lib

Tags: python, pyqt, virtualenv, pyqt5

I'm trying to compile [PyQt5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/introduction.html) for a [virtualenv](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/how-to-use-python-virtualenv/).  The problem is that it is looking for `Python27.lib` in `sys.prefix + '\\libs'`, which resolves to a non-existent libs directory in my virtualenv.  This is with [virtualenv 1.11](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).  There is an include folder, but no libs folder.

Seems like others would have run into this problem, either with [PyQt](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) or something else.  Is there a better solution than manually copying the libs folder into the virtual environment?

Answer (score -1):

you can try like this

> virtualenv --system-site-packages 'name of virtualenv'

After that you can access your system python libraries also. That could be fix your problem.

Comment: That would work for building PyQt into the system python, but I WANT to put it in the virtualenv instead.  I'm just having trouble with the build, since it is looking for something that isn't part of the virtualenv.

Comment: when creating a virtualenv, the flag `--system-site-packages` will create and populate the `Lib` folder, but will not create the `libs` folder with `python27.lib` on it